# Window not responding SFML

Tags: c++, sfml

I've just gotten into Sfml, and i am following a tutorial on youtube. My problem is that for some reason, the window just doesn't respond.
Here is my code:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
        sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(512, 512), "A* Algorithm", sf::Style::Close | sf::Style::Resize);

        while (window.isOpen());
        {
                sf::Event event;
                while (window.pollEvent(event))
                {
                        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                        {
                                window.close();
                        }
                        
                }
        }
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

When i downloaded SFML i also got some examples of programs using SFML, such as pong. Those programs do respond, also if i compile them, they still respond, and i can't seem to find the difference between how a window is opened there and how i open a window.
My operating system is Fedora 36.

Comment: What is the body of the following loop `while (window.isOpen());` ? It is empty because after while you have semicolon. You have just infinite loop which does nothing.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo !
There shouldn't be a ";" at the end of the first while() statement.

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues:

1. **A typo in line 9**

- *There shouldn't be a ';' at the end of line 9*

2. **Remember to call OpenGL render functions**

- *window.clear() & window.display()*

Here's how to use them:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main(int, char const**) 
{
    // Create the main window
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(512, 512), "A* Algorithm", sf::Style::Close | sf::Style::Resize);

    // Declare a drawable
    sf::RectangleShape rectangle;
    rectangle.setSize(sf::Vector2f(64.f, 64.f));
    rectangle.setPosition(sf::Vector2f(window.getSize().x/2.f - rectangle.getGlobalBounds().width/2.f, window.getSize().y/2.f - rectangle.getGlobalBounds().height/2.f));

    // Start the game loop
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        // Process events
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            // Close window: exit
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed) {
                window.close();
            }
        }

        // Clear screen
        window.clear();

        // Draw stuff between function calls
        window.draw(rectangle);

        // Update the window
        window.display();
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```